# DrawerLayout Menu is Blank with a Black Overlay - But on click the list populates

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

The problem is slightly tricky to explain, anyhow here it goes:

1. I have a drawerlayout with works well.
2. I have two fragments. The first fragment FragmentMainList opens from the mainactivity which displays a list of items. The second fragment FragmentPlayVideo is opened from the first Fragment on itemclicked on the list.
3. When i open the app, the app opens as expected with all the menu items of the drawer populated and visible
4. When i click on the item in the list in the first fragment, the second fragment opens as expected, however the menu drawer items have a black background. Not sure how this is happening. Please see below video:

https://youtu.be/RkD_eAzSF7U

**MainActivity.java**

```
package espn.example.com.espn;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentMainList.OnFragmentInteractionListener, FragmentPlayVideo.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.106:8080/Video/video.xml";
    static final String KEY_VIDEO = "video";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
    static final String KEY_VIDEO_URL = "video_url";
    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        isStoragePermissionGranted();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new FragmentMainList());
        ft.commit();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case 1: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new FragmentMainList());
                    ft.commit();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Storage Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_videos) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String uri) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(uri);
    }
}
```

**FragmentMainList.Java**

```
package espn.example.com.espn;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentMainList.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentMainList#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentMainList extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.106:8080/Video/video.xml";
    static final String KEY_VIDEO = "video";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
    static final String KEY_VIDEO_URL = "video_url";
    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";
    LayoutInflater inflaters;
    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentMainList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentMainList.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentMainList newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentMainList fragment = new FragmentMainList();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        inflaters = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(URL);
        onButtonPressed("Main List");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(String uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(String name);
    }
    private void populateListView() {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard,"output.xml");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Unable to Load Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("Unable to open output.xml");
        }
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >> videos = new ArrayList<>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(text.toString()); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_VIDEO);
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            final HashMap<String, String> map= new HashMap<>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
            map.put(KEY_VIDEO_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VIDEO_URL));
            videos.add(map);
        }
        list = getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(FragmentMainList.this, videos, inflaters);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                FragmentPlayVideo playVideoFragment = new FragmentPlayVideo ();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                playVideoFragment.setArguments(args);
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, playVideoFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
    }
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            System.out.println("Starting download");

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                System.out.println("Downloading");
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection urlConnection =  url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(SDCardRoot, "output.xml");
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                pDialog.setMax(totalSize);
                int downloadedSize = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                }
                fileOutput.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "failed";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "failed";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "success";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String status) {
            System.out.println("Downloaded");
            populateListView();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentPlayVideo.java**

```
package espn.example.com.espn;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentPlayVideo.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentPlayVideo#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentPlayVideo extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private MediaController mediaControls;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private View rootView;
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    public FragmentPlayVideo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentPlayVideo.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentPlayVideo newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentPlayVideo fragment = new FragmentPlayVideo();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play_video, container, false);
        String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
        System.out.println(value);
        videoView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        //String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_URL");
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getContext());
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        //Uri video = Uri.parse(s);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        //videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(s));
        videoView.start();
        onButtonPressed("Video");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play_video, container, false);
    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(String uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(String uri);
    }
}
```

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_header_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/espn2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="ESPN"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:text="On-Demand Streaming" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="espn.example.com.espn.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="espn.example.com.espn.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <!-- Note : This is the container Frame Layout for all the fragmetns-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_main_list.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="espn.example.com.espn.FragmentPlayVideo">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_play_video.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="espn.example.com.espn.FragmentPlayVideo">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Let me know if you need any more info. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing any video URI to the `VideoView`, that's why it remains black.

Try by hard coding your video URL.

For example,

```
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://youtu.be/RkD_eAzSF7U"));
videoView.start();
```

And regarding `DrawerLayout`'s black background, check the code of `@layout/nav_header_main`, may be its background color is black.

Comment: The videoview is not actually showing anything even after setting video URL - That's another issue that i am facing.
However, There is no black background set anywhere as you can see in the video, the drawer works fine when i first open it and after on click on the menu items

Comment: Hi, after adding the above code into the onActivityCreated method of the fragment all the issues got resolved. (P.S. Had to manually add that onActivityCreated method)

Comment: Glad you've found the solution.